# Flutter Auto tracking of sound playing in Listview with scrollcontroller

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

I have a music playlist in a ListView. The currently playing music row is highlighted. The music plays in sequential order. What I want to achieve is to automatically scroll the list to ensure that the currently playing music remains visible as it moves down the ListView. I'm sharing my ScrollController code below, but I'm not sure what approach to take. I need assistance with the code snippet.

```
 _scrollController.animateTo(
    0.0,
    duration: const Duration(
        milliseconds: 500),
    curve: Curves.easeInOut,
  );
```

I hope I was able to explain my problem.

Answer (score 0):

One easy way is to use `Scrollable.ensureVisible()` method.
Most likely your music items would have something that can be considered as their id, which makes each item unique and distinguishable from the others.
Let's assume the id is the path to the music file like "../musics/track1.mp3".
you can have a map from item id (path) to `GlobalKey`.

```
Map<String, GlobalKey> _keys = <String, GlobalKey>{};

...
// filling the map with songs' keys (file path)
_keys = <String, GlobalKey>{
      // Let's assume your model class for holding song information is `Song`.
      // and `songs` is the List<Song> you have.
      for (Song song in songs)
        // adding song path (id) as key and Global key as value to the map.
        song.path: GlobalKey(debugLabel: song.path)
    };
```

Where you create the ListView of your songs, on its itemBuilder, make sure you pass the corresponding key from the `_keys` map to the item widget

```
ListView.builder(
   itemBuilder: (context, index) {
      final GlobalKey<State<StatefulWidget>>? key =
                    _keys[song[index].path];

      return ListTile(
              title: Text(songs[index].name,
              key: key,
             );
   }
...
```

And when you want to scroll the list to a position that the current item is visible you need to have instance of the song and access it's key from `_keys` and call `ensureVisible`, it will also scroll in animation:

```
void scrollToCurrentSong(Song song) {
    final GlobalKey<State<StatefulWidget>>? key = _keys[song.path];

    if (key == null) {
       return;
    }


    WidgetsBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
          Scrollable.ensureVisible(
            key.currentContext!,
            curve: Curves.linear,
            duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 300),
          );
        });
}
```

PS: You can also have the `_keys` as a `List<GlobalKey` if you have the index of the item in the place you want to call `ensureVisible` to scroll to it. can retrieve the corresponding key from `_keys` like:

```
final GlobalKey<State<StatefulWidget>>? key = _keys[index];
```

Comment: @fatih-demir did the above solution work?